# Dropdown style overlapping issue while Chosen in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a droprdown i applied chosen style, i'm facing issue when i click dropdown, the dropdown options are getting overlapped as shown in the screen shot.
I tried to change the Z-index style & display in CSS nothing helped. 
Please help me on this.

Comment: What is the "Direct cost FTE Offshore" block? and what z-index does it have? (just curious if the green bit is an iframe for example... if so, you won't be able to solve this without using a native <select> element.)

Comment: html table block and there is no Z-index applied for this block